# Very similar implementations of binarySearch with different parameters works equally fine. Why?

Tags: c, function

I was trying to make my own binary search function for a university project and came up with this:

```
int bSearch(int data[], int dim, int num)
{
    if(dim == 0)
        return 0;
    if(num == data[(dim-1)/2])
        return 1;
    if(num < data[(dim-1)/2])
        return bSearch(data,(dim-1)/2 - 1, num);
    if(num > data[(dim-1)/2])
        return bSearch(data + ((dim-1)/2) + 1, dim - (dim-1)/2 - 1 , num);
}
```

One of my friends came up with almost the same function but wherever I put `(dim-1)/2` he wrote `dim/2`, and it looks like both are working equally fine, I came up with the `(dim-1)/2` while trying a few examples and seemed to work.

Why does this difference (not) matter?

Comment: Compare what your implementations do when searching `{0, 1}` for `0`.

Comment: Mine returns 1 in the first call and my friend's takes one more call, right?

Comment: Is it *supposed* to return 1? In that case, compare what your implementations do when searching `{0, 1}` for `1`.

Comment: 1 being returned means the number is in the array, 0 means it is not, let me check that. (Btw, how do you get your code to look like that in the comments?)

Comment: Backticks. They're next to the `1` on your keyboard. \`thing\` produces `thing`. If you're only supposed to return a contained/not contained flag, rather than the actual index, then `dim/2` or `(dim-1)/2` shouldn't matter.

Comment: To understand the differences, perhaps you should instrument the two versions, and see how they differ.  You might simply put `printf("dim = %d; mid = %d\n", dim, (dim - 1)/2);` in your code, and use `dim/2` in his code. I'd put that before the `if (num == data[(dim - 1)/2])` test. Then try searching for the same values in the same arrays for various values and array sizes, so you see the different checks that are made.

Comment: And if you want to get really fast (which this isn't) you use `dim/2` because it compiles to a single shift operation. Actually, reading about super-fast bsearch algorithms leads into fixed length parallel SSE stuff which is crazy-awesome.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that how it divides the table in two to see in which section it is.

Traditionally you'd divide it in half, but you could divide it 10% and 90% and see in which section it is and it would also work, just wouldn't be optimal.

In your example, if you have a list with 10 numbers, it'd check the 4th to see if it's the number, then if it's not it'd see if it's smaller than the 4th and if it's not, it'd check to see if it's bigger. Your friends would do the same but with the 5th as the reference point. Both would work, but his is probably gonna be slightly faster for big tables.

Comment: Hmm, but doesn't my function still divide the table in two (for the case where dim is odd, else there is no middle element)?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD you're both gonna get the same number for an odd number, because a division of ints returns an int, so if you have 11 elements, `11/2 = 5`  and `(11 - 1)/2 = 5`